# Controlling gameObject with WiiRemote

Tags: unity, wii

I would like to get some information on how I can control my gameObject with a wiiRemote. Can't seem te find a decent guide on how to implement the WiiRemote into Unity.

My game is just a simple catch-game in 2D. Balls falling from the sky, and need to be collected in a bowl. 
The player is controlling a stick (Controlled by WiiRemote) that has to lead the balls to the bowl.
I would like to be able to move the stick using the WiiRemote, and rotate the stick by turning the WiiRemote.

So far I seem to be able to connect my WiiRemote to my PC (windows), but I have no idea how to read the input from it in Unity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [interfacing WiiMote with Unity 5](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/100468/interfacing-wiimote-with-unity-5)