# Using a Wii remote as main controller?

Tags: unity, input, wii

I would like to use a Wii remote to control my player in my 3D game.

So far I have the arrow keys and mouse to move and look but I want the Wii d-pad to move and accelerometer data to look around.

I have downloaded [Unity-Wiimote-1.1](https://github.com/Flafla2/Unity-Wiimote/releases) and the demo works fine. In my game I have imported the Unity package for the Wii remote but I'm not sure what script goes where, attached to what, how to call particular functions. They are mostly C# scripts.

There is no documentation with the Unity-Wiimote-1.1 and as I'm a newbie, I'm clueless on what to do.

Or is there a simpler method to getting the Wii remote to be the main controller?

Comment: Do you have the development kit officially from Nintendo?

Comment: We have another question on [interfacing WiiMote with Unity 5](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/100468/interfacing-wiimote-with-unity-5) which may be worth a look. Neither answer uses Unity-Wiimote-1.1 specifically, but it might be good to edit & revive that question to keep the Unity-Wii interfacing options all on one page.

Comment: Step 1: Figure out what's used in the example scene and where. Step 2: pour over the classes involved. Step 3: Post an answer for future users to find.

Comment: Hey all, sorry for the delay in repsonse. @RamaAlifiandy: No i haven't, i wasn't sure i needed it.

Comment: @DMGregory: Yeah i'll have a look through all that. I did that post before but didn't scroll all the way down haha. I'm sure there's something there i can use.

Comment: @Draco18s: The demo uses a different script, specifically for the demo but i'll have a look through. What i'm attempting now it to use the wii remote in Max/MSP and have the data sent to Unity as Max is my host application.