# Accessing DualShock 4 motion sensor in Windows

Tags: c#, unity, gamepad, motion-control

I am attempting to access the accelerometer and gyroscope functionality of the dualshock 4 controller for implementation into Unity.

DMGregory seems to have found a solution to this problem, my question is how he succeeded in getting the motion input working [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/87106/accessing-dualshock-4-motion-sensor-in-windows-ideally-unity).

He mentions that he reached his solution by grabbing the DS4Tool source and copying parts of the files: **NativeMethods, HidDevices** and **HidDevice**

I understand a lot of what is happening here, I just do not have the coding chops to get it working. I believe I should be "using **NativeMethods**" but do not fully understand how to access the read report to retrieve the necessary data.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Generally you want to comment on an answer asking for clarification if some aspect of that answer isn't clear to you, or you need additional details; don't re-ask the question. Since you cannot comment on answers that aren't your own yet, I've done so for you.

Comment: Alternatively, if you are having a *specific* issue such as a compiler error or specific runtime error, you can update your post to include that clarifying information so that it's not just a repeat of an existing question; you have to be specific though, as "I don't know how to make it work" is too broad.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the repost, I had attempted to comment but this seemed to be my only option

Comment: Sorry that answer was a bit light — I was still finding my StackExchange groove two yeara ago. ;) I'll expand it a bit further soon (travelling just now). If you ever need to reach me for more info on an answer, you can also tweet @D_M_Gregory