# How to use a DualShock 4 controller in Java?

Tags: java

I want to use a DualShock 4 controller in a computer program I'm developing.

Do I only need to use a library? Or do I need some other things too?

I don't have any code yet, I'm just starting to look at it. I'll be using Eclipse if it has any relevance.

Comment: When [I've investigated this in the past with Unity and C#](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/87106/accessing-dualshock-4-motion-sensor-in-windows-ideally-unity), I needed to hook into OS-level Human Interface Device handling (like Kernel32.dll on Windows). Then again, I was trying to get at motion sensor data, which is not exposed well in many existing libraries/tools. If you just need button and analog stick/trigger inputs, you may be able to get those from more generic gamepad methods.

Comment: [gamepad4j](https://github.com/marcelschoen/gamepad4j) claims to have out of the box support for DualShock 4. A casual peek at the code agrees with @DMGregory - it hooks into lower level OS specific code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LibGDX](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) is a Java-based engine that has support for [Controllers](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/09/22/LibGDX-Tutorial-Part-14-Gamepad-support.aspx). However, you would have to do some research on what Input ID is used for the DualShock 4.

Comment: This answer could be even better if it included a rough outline of how to read DualShock 4 input with this library.