# Vibration/Rumble with PS4 Pad and LPDIRECTINPUTDEVICE8

Tags: input, windows, gamepad, playstation4, directinput

I actually try to make my PS4 Pad rumble.
I get the pad capabilities with

```
DIDEVCAPS capabilities;
capabilities.dwSize = sizeof(DIDEVCAPS);
ps4pad->GetCapabilities(&capabilities);
```

the next step is to check if the flag `DIDC_FORCEFEEDBACK` is ok

But `capabilities.dwFlags & DIDC_FORCEFEEDBACK` always return false.

As my pad is a ps4, I know it support feedback.

Have you an idea why it's return false, what I missed?

Comment: Some features of the DualShock4 might not be exposed to DirectInput. For instance, [in the past I've had to dig through the bytes of the HID reports myself to get at the motion sensor data](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/87178/39518). [This guide has information on where to find the rumble bytes in the output report](http://eleccelerator.com/wiki/index.php?title=DualShock_4#HID_OUTPUT), if you want to go that route.

Comment: I use my PS4 pad with a Sony Dongle (https://www.playstation.com/en-gb/explore/accessories/dualshock-4-usb-wireless-adaptor/) and that supports rumble for at least Rocket League on Windows. Doesn't seem to work on OSX, though Steam Big Picture is able to rumble it on OSX.

Answer (score 2):

Windows lacks DirectInput support for DS4 gamepads. In general there's no standard way to do haptics for HID gamepads, and the DS4 isn't even really a standard HID gamepad.

To get this working in Chrome I had to send the vibration commands as raw HID packets:

https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/device/gamepad/dualshock4_controller_base.cc?l=45

https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/device/gamepad/dualshock4_controller_win.cc?l=38

You can also use third-party drivers like DS4Windows to make your DS4 behave like an XInput device.