# Using DualShock 4 motion sensor in Unreal engine (windows)

Tags: unreal, controllers, motion-control

Anyone know how to access the gyro/accelerometer values from a DualShock 4 controller in the Unreal engine (under windows)? Are there any plugins that do this? Does raw input work?

Comment: [I had to solve this problem in Unity a few years ago](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/87106/39518), so you may find some useful leads in that previous Q&A.

Answer (score -1):

There is a plugin indeed, but it's closed source. You need to be a registered PS4 dev to get it.

Comment: This answer would be better if it included more details about the process. Maybe include the name of the plugin? What steps one would need to follow to enable it in Unreal Engine? Any other info that might be needed?