# What is the PS5 DualSense gyroscope and accelerometer values range?

Tags: input, gamepad, gyroscope, sensor-fusion, playstation5

I'm trying to implement aiming in shooter using gyroscope but I can't find the minimum and maximum value for each axis to normalize it to range (-1;1)

What is the possible values range?

Comment: A rate gyroscope measures the speed of rotation. So, the faster you turn it, the higher a number you will read. The same goes for an accelerometer - the faster you accelerate/decelerate the controller, the higher the values. It might not make sense to speak of a max value in this context - the maximum rotation speed/acceleration the sensor can reliably detect might be well above the maximum speed that a player's wrists can comfortably manipulate the controller. So you may want to base your gameplay bounds on empirical measures of comfort instead.

Comment: @DMGregory what units of that values are? Is there any docs where can I find information about PS5 gyroscope?

Comment: [In the comments on this similar question about the DualShock 4, someone was able to identify the specific IMU chip that the controller used, and found its units there](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/87106/accessing-dualshock-4-motion-sensor-in-windows-ideally-unity#comment278103_87178). You may want to check whether the DualShock 5 matches the same convention, or if you can follow the same route of finding documentation related to the specific chip used inside.